# SQL Server : query to replace data

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to take all passwords for a live SQL Server database, and replace them with passwords from a backup.

Basic table setup:

`Main`:

```
Account_ID   Username    Password
----------------------------------
    1        Blah        gy12uid91
    2        Blah2       gy12uid92
```

`Backup`:

```
Account_ID   Username   Password
----------------------------------
   1         Blah       xxxxxxxx
   2         Blah2      xxxxxxxx
```

I need to take ONLY the passwords from the backup database, and put them in where the username is the same as the live database, so that both would be the same, but only where the usernames are the same.

I was thinking some kind of query like:

```
UPDATE livedb 
FROM backupdb 
WHERE username ='name'
SET password ='xxxxxxxx'
WHERE username ='name'
```

In other words, I have 3600 rows and need to change all the passwords on a massive scale without just copy pasting.

Comment: I don't think you can do that without an intermediary storage (PHP)...

Comment: Care to explain further? I can do whatever is needed, I just don't know what IS needed.

Comment: Have you restored the database to another location or do you have the table restored in the same database?

Comment: These are password _hashes_, right?

Comment: If you need (URGENT) help, hire a contractor. Your question here is no more urgent or important than anyone else. Also, your question title should contain information about the content of your question - "MSSQL Query" contains none, as the sql-server tag already shows you're using MSSQL. Please [edit] your title so that it reflects the actual problem you're asking for help solving; it should also have information that will be useful to future readers who find it in a search result. Thanks.

Comment: I would, in PHP, select old backup, match by ID, update to new DB.

Comment: @OCIA good advice. I don't know PHP, but I am making a C# program instead to do just that.

Comment: @DavidG the backup and the live database are stored on the same SQL server, but are not the same.

Comment: @KenWhite you are right, I just hadn't thought about that. I am sorry for making my problems seem like everyone elses problems. I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks!

Comment: Please tell me you're **not actually** storing those passwords in **clear text** in your database!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE l
SET password=b.password
FROM Livedb.schema.table l
INNER JOIN backupdb.schema.table b
  ON l.Username=b.Username
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your database restored to another location on the same server and the database are called `live` and `restored`:

```
UPDATE liveUsers
SET liveUsers.password = restoredUsers.password
FROM live.users liveUsers
JOIN restored.users restoredUsers
    ON liveUsers.Account_ID = restoredUsers.Account_ID
```

This will replace the `password` column form `restored` into `live` by matching on `Account_ID`